# Does FLUX app "push" data updated to its views?

Tags: flux

I'm reading some intro information about the FLUX pattern, and before going deeper I'd like to know if it's possible to run a server daemon in the background, that updates the data (stores) and see it reflected immediately in the HTML (without polling requests).

The flow I have in mind:  The daemon updates the data => the store sends an "change" event => the controller-view receives the "change" and triggers "render" => The view(html) is updated. Reminds me a push-notification flow.

Is anyone familiar with this behavior/scenaio?

Answer (score 1):

There is a debate whether the stores should fetch data by using ajax request or as will probably happen in your case server-sent events. My opinion is that the store should react only on actions. So, you should probably create a service that deals with the data management (pushing from the server). Then that service fires an action that there is a new data and the store take it from there. Keeping the actual data requesting/retrieving outside the store makes it simpler and easy to test. At least that's my experience.

P.S.
I'll also question placing data fetching/retrieving processes in an action. For me the action should be like a signal. Just a simple data (value) object flying through the app.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems like I have to go deeper with my flux learning in order to understand your answer well :) Anyway, when you say the the store fetches the data - it means it makes a request with a query each couple of seconds (polling) to check if a new data present?

Comment: I see. Even in this case I'll go with keeping such logic outside the store. It seems better keeping the store doing one thing - updating its state based on actions. If the actual fetching process is there will start making two jobs. By the way I recently blogged about flux [here](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/dissection-of-flux-architecture-or-how-to-write-your-own-react). You may find some ideas helpful.